# Не работает drag в яндекс картах

Tags: 1с, карты, drag-n-drop, webkit

В 1С начал использоваться webKit и в нем не работает drag для яндекс карт.
map.behaviors.enable([ 'drag']) не помогает.

Comment: Та же беда. Пока не знаю, что делать. Откатился на 8.3.13, но это не выход конечно...